# Getting connection refused error when trying to connect to Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I have gone through all the steps to connect to my Android TV to sideload test apps over the air and keep getting a "Connection refused" error when I run "adb connect 192.168.0.48:5555". I've turned on USB debugging, restarted the computer and the Android TV and still no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you confirm the IP address of your Android TV? You can check it from [Settings] -> [Network] -> [Advanced settings] -> [Network status].

Comment: @corochann - yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had no other option than to go this route:

http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/android-tv-guides/how-to-sideload-apps-apk-files-on-the-nexus-player-or-adt-1/

Then I installed Google Drive and use it to sideload apks...

By the way, in the last step of the instructions (when you are ready to install the apps you have put un the download folder) because of the way AndroidTV manages the DPad (and the fact the ESFileExplorer is not optimized for the remote), you need to move the DPad on the left menu to a menu item directly to the left of the apk icons that are on the right panel -- THEN you can DPad over to them!

Answer (score 1):

Try without the PORT being specified on the connect command.

I had this exact issue with my Sony Bravia, I had done all the rebooting etc but after doing it again today and trying with just the IP and no port specified it all worked!

Just so others are aware when working with Sony TVs, USB debugging is not supported as of writing this, so connecting it with a USB cable is not going to solve your issues.

Comment: i just tried that and adb automatically added post :5555 and still did not connect. I guess I will mark my own solution as correct :-/